# how to perform multiple transactions in one request

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm using Neo4J REST API to do in separated requests:

- request 1 - create user node (and get node id)
- request 2 - add User label to created node
- request 3 - create picture node (and get node id)
- request 4 - add Picture label to created node
- request 5 - create relationship between nodes with created id's

Is there any way to perform all this operations in one single request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to create a single Cypher query that combines everything into a single request.  Keep in mind that you don't need the node ID if you're simply operating on it during the Cypher query.

You can use either the Cypher endpoint or the Transactional HTTP endpoint.  In this case, it's probably easiest to use the Cypher endpoint (the only difference here is that the Cypher endpoint automatically tries to commit a transaction at the end of the request whereas the Transactional HTTP endpoint can span multiple requests even though it can still be used for a single request).

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-cypher.html has a lot of info on the Cypher endpoint, and http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-transactional.html has info on the Transactional HTTP endpoint.

TL;DR version: /db/data/cypher is likely the endpoint you want to issue the request against.

The Cypher query itself should be pretty straightforward, too; something like:

```
CREATE (u:User)-[:REL_TYPE]->(p:Picture)
```

...of course if you need to do multiple such inserts, perhaps looking at a batch operation might not be a bad idea, especially if your Cypher query gets too long (have a look at the Transactional HTTP endpoint for more info; it's pretty straightforward).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually `POST /db/data/transaction/commit` is the endpoint you want to use. `CREATE (u:User {name:{name}})-[:REL_TYPE]->(p:Picture {url:{url}}) RETURN id(u), id(p)` Also check out the Cypher Reference card and the `MERGE` command. http://neo4j.org/resources/cypher

Comment: According to http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-transactional.html it says: "The key difference between the transactional HTTP endpoint and the Cypher endpoint (see Section 19.5, “Cypher queries via REST”) is the ability to use the same transaction across multiple HTTP requests. The cypher endpoint always attempts to commit a transaction at the end of each HTTP request."   ...so if the OP wants to do a single Cypher query, could he not just go against /db/data/cypher as it says in the link above?